# Python parsing with bs4

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r=requests.get("https://www.pexels.com/photo/sunglasses-sunset-summer-sand- 
46710/")
cont=r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(cont,"html.parser")
img=soup.findAll('src')
print(img)
```

I cant have src text,my code is returning empty string,how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you're trying to get the glasses picture from the link. You should've posted the source atleast. But anyways, in your code you're trying to get the 'src' from the HTML, even though there are no tags called 'src'. It belongs to a 'img' tag, so that's what you should be looking for, and then the src. I looked into the URL, and the image you're trying to look for has a class of `image-section__image`. You can use that to find your image. I'll post the snippet:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
img = soup.find('img', class_='image-section__image')
print(img['src'])
```